# Can the hysteresis phenomenon be considered as a (type of) friction

Tags: mechanical-engineering, friction

I was wondering whether the hysteresis (in particular, mechanical motion systems) can be considered under the class of friction.

From theory, I know that the frictional forces are direction, and velocity dependent. In the same sense, they also possess memory in the special cases of frictions. So, is it correct (without abusing any definitions) to consider the hysteresis observed in motion systems to be under the class of friction. Because the hysteresis in motion systems also characterises the same characteristics.

Simply put, under what conditions one can classify the hysteresis under the frictional nonlinearity, and if not, under which conditions this fails to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hysteresis is not the same as friction, but friction is part of hysteresis, it is normally considered as the play or "free movement" in joints etc that cause a system to take a slightly different route "down or return" compared to the "up or outward" travel.

Comment: Ya I agree, but isn't it same as let's say stribeck effect with memory (that depends upon time and itself)?

Comment: If you want to take this into the field of tribology, then you should start a new question.

Comment: Yes, I shall do that.